# The argument type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
              value: value,
              items: locationItems.map( DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text( widget.locationName ),
                value: "${widget.locationName}",
              )
              ),
```

Comment: Can you describe the code-snippet?  How you've defined `value` and `locationItems`?

Answer (score 3):

Map returns iteratable. Try to convert it to list.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
              value: value,
              items: locationItems.map( DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text( widget.locationName ),
                value: "${widget.locationName}",
              )
              ).toList<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(),
```

Comment: The named parameter 'onChanged' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.

Comment: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'.

Comment: Cast it. toList<DropdownMenuItem<String>>()

Comment: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'.

Comment: DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    data["location_name"],
                  ),
                  value: "${data["location_name"]}",
                )
              ).toList<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();
            }
            return DropdownButton<String>(
              items: locationItem,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  value = value;
                });
              },
            );

Answer (score 0):

The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?

Make your declared variable as the type above will solve your poblem